# Auto sync for local DB with sync adapters

Tags: android, adapter, synchronization, account

I am writing a sync application using sync adapter,and try to sync local db automatically, First time when i create account it works fine but when i make changes in the local db, it is not syncing automatically even if i set ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true).

Comment: one has to call contentResolver.notifychange(Uri,contentObserver,true) after each transaction in the database.for example after every insert transaction  call NOtifyChange it will notify to the corresponding sync Adapter bound to the Authority of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), 1);
```